# Android Dictionary app

Tags: android, database, android-studio, dictionary

I am going to create an android dictionary application which goal is to translate my mother language (Zazaki) to Turkish.
I have 2 documents which have a format like below:

> Zazaki to Turkish word docs
>   ban: ev ====> home
>
> Turkish to Zazaki
>   ev: ban, çe ===> home

In my mind, first taking word before colon as key, after colon as value.
Then putting it into a database.

My question is:
"Do I have to do this operation for every time?
How can I make this database available for every download by not importing the  word list documents into my database"?

Comment: Why not having a pre-filled database and ship your app with that, instead? You'll only need 2 tables with the words and their unique ids (one table per language) and a connector table which connects the ids between the tables. So you will make a bidirectional many to many relationship.

Comment: I check your answer about pre-filled database. Should i use 2 DBs in that case ?

Comment: NO. One db can contain any number of tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you have excel, it's quite easy to make a word document into a database , by splitting by ' ' and deleting the resulting columns you don't need. You can then export it, e.g. into a .csv file.

For your request, I would use the following pseudo-code as a guide for my code:

```
int currIndex = 0;
string key, value;
while(!EndOfFile){
    currIndex = find('=');
    key = getWordBeforeCurrentIndex();
    currIndex = find('>');
    value = getWordAfterCurrentIndex();
    myDictionary.Add(key, value);
}
```

Make that into real code and voila - you got yourself an app parsing a document into a dictionary.

If you know that your document has an exact format like:

> ev ====> home
>
> word2 ===> translation2
>
> word3 ===> translation3

You can of course leverage this and go

```
Dictionary myDict = new HashTable<string, string>();
InputStream wordDictionary = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.wordDictionary);
DataInputStream myDIS = new DataInputStream(wordDictionary);

ArrayList<string> lines = new ArrayList<Lines>();
string currLine;
//Read document into arraylist:
while((myLine=myDIS.readline())!=null) list.add(myLine);
//Take each line, add left word as key, add right word as value:
foreach(line : lines){
    myDict.add(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" ")), line.substring(line.indexOf(" ", line.indexOf(" ")+1));
}
```

Comment: should i add word documents to resources?

Comment: Either that, or put it in the file system and find it there. Should google "android read file from system" for that, since I can't think of that function right now^^